# Let $n>0$ and $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$. Then there exists $z$ on $|z|=1$ such that $|p(z) | \geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried a proof by contradiction using Rouche's theorem but I couldn't see how 
Rouche's theorem would help in this situation.

What would happen if $|p(z)|<1$ for all  $z$ in $|z|=1$

Could somebody help me out?

New approaches are welcome.

Comment: That can't be true. Take $p(z)=z/2$ for instance.

Comment: One has any assumption imposed on $a_n, n>0$? If not, then consider $p(z)=a_1z$ with $|a_1|<1$.

Comment: I made mistake. Actually we assume $a_n = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |p(e^{it})|^2\, dt.$$

Comment: Could you give me more details?  I can't  see the contradiction.

Comment: The integral is $2\pi(1+\sum_i|a_i|^2)$.